# Word or morpheme for “middle” or “not above or below”, as opposed to “super” and “sub”?

Tags: prefix

What is a latin morpheme for “middle” which can be used as a prefix, instead of “sub“ and “super”?

The context is the use of such a construct in English. So the following mentions some English examples.

One can say “subscript“ and “superscript”, and normal text is probably just “script”. But it might sometimes be useful to use a prefix which means “normal“ or “middle”, to make the distinction clear. You can also say “subordinate” and “superordinate” (though “superior” is probably more common), but there is apparently no similar word for “colleague” or “peer”. (By the way: one can not use the word “ordinate” itself for that, according to Merriam-Webster.)

Comment: In English I would be inclined to say "midscript" to refer to normal text as opposed to "subscript" and "superscript". For a more Latin prefix (that could be used in Latin), perhaps *inter-* or *medio-*, but I don't have any examples to show how appropriate these are.

Comment: This probably belongs on ELU, as it's asking about English words, which happen to use borrowed Latin.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I originally asked this question there, but then a commenter said that I should post it *here* instead...

Comment: That commenter likely didn't know what they were talking about, then. It's far from uncommon for people to recommend posting a question on another site when they know nothing about that site but its title

Comment: Welcome! Most SE are unreasonably exclusive. We're still young and naïve and we're trying to be open and welcoming. I think this question is perfectly fine either on English.SE or here.

Comment: When cross posting, please link to the original question (if you haven't deleted it).

Comment: @Earthliŋ I did delete it. Last I heard duplicate questions were disallowed.

Comment: Discouraged, yes, but in case it's not clear on which site the question belongs, it is sometimes helpful to have both versions live (with the appropriate links) until it has become clear (looking at the comments of both communities) which question should be deleted.

Comment: @Earthliŋ is correct. In some cases it might be good to have the question on different SE sites (but not twice on the same site). You can find some discussion and guidelines in [this meta question](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/159/79).

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned [inscript](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inscript).

Comment: @cmw, no, OP was right that the level between _super-_ and _sub-_ is just no prefix at all, at least in the case of script. _In_-scription is going along the wrong axis (−Z) to be appropriate here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with Latin *medi(o)-* or Greek *meso-*.

*Medi-* comes from Latin *medius* meaning "in the middle, moderate, indifferent". It's also the root of "medium" and "medial"; as a prefix, the first usage that comes to mind is the Greek *mediopassive voice* (i.e. a combination of the middle voice and the passive voice).

*Meso-* comes from the Greek *μέσος*, cognate to *medius*, also meaning "in between, moderate," etc. In English it's mostly used in place names (Mesopotamia, Mesoamerica) and scientific terms (meso-compounds in chemistry are neither right- nor left-handed).

Both of these are also related to the English "mid-" as in "midpoint" and "midway", which is the least technical and most easily understood of the three.